# reporter.log() testng equivalent in nunit

Tags: java, .net, nunit, testng

I am assigned to a new project to be automated in .net the test runner that I am using is NUnit, I used to work in Java and I used to use Testng and the reporter class to printout my report in the Index.html, is there a way of doing the same in UNuit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NUnit generates only XML report.
You can create html report from XML using third party tools like [ReportUnit](http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit-report-generator/) or any other.